# Downloading a specific version of solc within a Docker image

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, docker

I am working with the release of Solidity v0.4.25 for it works well with py-solc. When running on a local machine the codebase works quite well with 0.4.25. My issue currently is to get the codebase running on a Docker image with Ubuntu. I initially tried installing the Ubuntu PPA but the release that is currently out does not work with my code. Anyone know how to get 0.4.25 installed via the Dockerfile? (first time I have ever asked a question on exchange so quite desperate here).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get 0.4.25 version of solc installed in your Docker-image, you could do something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu
...
RUN curl -o /usr/bin/solc -fL https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/download/v0.4.25/solc-static-linux \
    && chmod u+x /usr/bin/solc
...
```